# How to configure custom nameservers with dedicated server and different domain Provider

Tags: dns, nameservers, spf, dkim, dedicated-server

I would like to know how to point mydomain.it to my dedicated server.

## I explain my situation:

- I have a Dedicated server on SingleHop.
- I have the domain "mydomain.it" on Siteground.

I created on my Dedicated server the nameserver:

- ns1.mydomain.it with IP 1.2.3.4 and
- ns2.mydomain.it. with IP 1.2.3.5

Now, I wish to control all DNS settings on my dedicated server because of SPF record and DKIM record and SSL Certification, but I can't tell Siteground to point the IP 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5 on my nameservers, because there is only space for the nameservers text (ns1.mydomain.it and ns2.mydomain.it) and there is not space for the IP field.

Without the IP, the domain's nameservers can't point to my dedicated server, and I can't manage DNS settings. So I ask myself what I could do for make sense to this story.

There is a way to do this? 
Please help me,

Thank you.
Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the DNS system was first conceived there were two addressing mechanisms that were used. The 32 bit IP Address, and the 16 bit octal Chaos Address. To make these systems easier to administer the NS record is specified as being a name rather than an address. (otherwise you would need different names for each protocol)

As it turned out, that wasn't needed as Chaos quickly died out (at least as an addressing scheme) but the original idea of having a name that then needs to be resolved to an address remains.

For this reason you can only specify a fully qualified domain name in the NS record. There are mechanisms that you can use if the domain name is on the domain you wish to create the record for (glue records) but that is quite a complicated aspect of DNS.

Aside from that though, I would say that it is very rarely a good idea to run your own name server. It is an extremely complicated - and expensive - thing to do correctly.

Weighing that against the simplicity and negligible cost of using a service to host your domain name. Who will invariably provide a global DNS infrastructure to ensure that your domain is constantly available.

Finally the majority of DNS Services all offer easy configuration of DKIM and SPF (SSL isn't something that is provided at the DNS level, it is merely part of the lookup to validate it)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.

I had resolved using Gmail for Works as Server Mail, and pointing A record to my Dedicated server.

But I would like to know yet how to do the configuration above, maybe with Glue Record. (Are there some registrars could do this?)

Thanks again!

Comment: @michele.falconi I have a feeling you are trying to solve the wrong problem somewhere here. What is it you are wanting to achieve, what is the end result you hope for?